# Why I get nil from singleton object?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have class `OauthObject` with singleton (file .m):

```
+ (OauthObject*) sharedManager{

    static OauthObject* manager = nil;

    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        manager = [[OauthObject alloc] init];
    });

    return manager;
}
@end
```

There is a `property` in `.h` file:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *access_token;
```

In this class I set variable `access_token` to `@"1234567"`

At another file `TableViewControler.m` I have import of `OauthObject`:

`#import "OauthObject.h"`

Below in the method I try to get value `access_token` like as:

`[[OauthObject sharedManager] access_token]; // It should be 1234567`

But I get `nil`

I set `access_tokes` as:

```
NSString *accessToken = [[OauthObject sharedManager] access_token];
accessToken = [responseObject objectForKey:@"access_token"];
```

Comment: well, not your singleton is nil, but your property, which has nothing to do with the singleton fact. *where* do you assign anything to the `access_token`?

Comment: Did you debug at all? What additional info did you learn?

Comment: How did you set the access_token ? Can you add the code where you are setting that value ?

Comment: Seem I know, how I can set `access_token`? Likes as: `[[OauthObject sharedManager] access_token] = @"1234567";` ? It gives me error

Comment: Gardash@do u set it in singleTon object?

Comment: Yes, but I dont know if I do it correct, I showed it in question

Comment: Instead for setting it in OathObject set it where u get response object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the `access_token` like this:

```
[OauthObject sharedManager].access_token = [responseObject objectForKey:@"access_token"]
```

or

```
[[OauthObject sharedManager] setAccess_token:[responseObject objectForKey:@"access_token"]]
```

---

In your question, you tried like this:

```
NSString *accessToken = [[OauthObject sharedManager] access_token];
accessToken = [responseObject objectForKey:@"access_token"];
```

In the first line, you assigned `access_token` of [OauthObject sharedManager] to the variable `accessToken`. But in the second line you just change the value of variable instead of the property in `OauthObject` instance.